# Android google maps navigation and setting markers

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

I tried to set a marker using :

```
 Marker marker=mMap.addMarker(
           new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(13.058375,80.236052)));
```

but when I run it I keep getting this error , what should I do ?

```
09-22 09:59:09.928    7272-7272/? E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.domobile.eframe.DatabaseErrorActivity has leaked window android.widget.FrameLayout{26b505bc VFE...C. .F...... 0,0-720,1134} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:375)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1058)
            at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:887)
            at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:851)
            at com.domobile.frame.ui.e.run(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Well first of all That error is no where Related to Marker,Your Trying to do some Function on Activity after you already exited That Activity**

**Look at this for Clear Understanding**

[Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Comment: i haven't done any other coding in that activity except these 3 lines . @rajan ks